# Shortest path finder from a JSON in #

Tags: c#, json, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have a JSON as follows-

```
[
  {
    "From": "Sydney",
    "To": "Dubai",
    "Duration": 1
  },
  {
    "From": "Dubai",
    "To": "Venice",
    "Duration": 2
  },
  {
    "From": "Venice",
    "To": "Rio",
    "Duration": 3
  },
  {
    "From": "Venice",
    "To": "Sydney",
    "Duration": 1
  },
  {
    "From": "Sydney",
    "To": "Rio",
    "Duration": 7
  }
]
```

I want find the shortest path between the cities in the JSON. The idea is to develop a method which takes in only ONE City name as input and displays the shortest path to all other destination.

So lets let say we have provided Sydney as a input, the output I'm looking for is

```
Selected City: Sydney
To 1: Dubai, Smallest Path Length: 1, Path: Sydney, Dubai.
To 2: Venice, Smallest Path Length: 3, Path: Sydney, Dubai, Venice.
To 3: Rio, Smallest Path Length: 6, Path: Sydney, Dubai, Venice, Rio.

(N.B. Sydney-Rio is 7 hours long hence Sydney-Dubai-Venice-Rio
 is the shortest route here which takes 2 hours).
```

My attempt-

```
var json = [
      {
        "From": "Sydney",
        "To": "Dubai",
        "Duration": 1
      },
      {
        "From": "Dubai",
        "To": "Venice",
        "Duration": 2
      },
      {
        "From": "Venice",
        "To": "Rio",
        "Duration": 3
      },
      {
        "From": "Venice",
        "To": "Sydney",
        "Duration": 1
      },
      {
        "From": "Sydney",
        "To": "Rio",
        "Duration": 7
      }
    ]



public string Path(string city, JObject json)
        {
            string result = null;

            return result;
        }

        private void xBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Path(xBox.SelectedText, json);
        }
```

Now to develop a method which takes care of the above....
But how? I'm scratching my head!!!!

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Surely you are not wanting to do path finding on the JSON?

Comment: @Plutonix I am actually, if possible

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm is an algorithm for finding the shortest paths between nodes in a graph, which may represent, for example, road networks.
Try to implement this algorithm and ask for advice if you get stuck somewhere.
You can read about algorithm here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Here are the steps of the algorithm:
Let the node at which we are starting be called the initial node. Let the distance of node Y be the distance from the initial node to Y. Dijkstra's algorithm will assign some initial distance values and will try to improve them step by step.

1. Assign to every node a tentative distance value: set it to zero for our initial node and to infinity for all other nodes.
2. Set the initial node as current. Mark all other nodes unvisited. Create a set of all the unvisited nodes called the unvisited set.
3. For the current node, consider all of its unvisited neighbors and calculate their tentative distances. Compare the newly calculated tentative distance to the current assigned value and assign the smaller one. For example, if the current node A is marked with a distance of 6, and the edge connecting it with a neighbor B has length 2, then the distance to B (through A) will be 6 + 2 = 8. If B was previously marked with a distance greater than 8 then change it to 8. Otherwise, keep the current value.
4. When we are done considering all of the neighbors of the current node, mark the current node as visited and remove it from the unvisited set. A visited node will never be checked again.
5. If the destination node has been marked visited (when planning a route between two specific nodes) or if the smallest tentative distance among the nodes in the unvisited set is infinity (when planning a complete traversal; occurs when there is no connection between the initial node and remaining unvisited nodes), then stop. The algorithm has finished.
6. Otherwise, select the unvisited node that is marked with the smallest tentative distance, set it as the new "current node", and go back to step 3.